# Not possible to scroll with ionic list

Tags: list, scroll, ionic-framework

Hi everyone I am very new to ionic and here's my problem. 
In the following view I find it impossible to scroll down. I don't know where it comes from and I have read similar posts relating to ionic list but couldn't find a solution that works for me ! 
Here's my code

```
<ion-view view-title="footparams">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="list text-center has-header">
      <a class="item item-icon-left top" href="#">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-25">
           <img class= "icon_size_edit_foot"        src="../img/icon_disponibilite.svg"/>
          </div>
         <div class="col col-75">
         <p class="dispo">Disponibilité du terrain</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col col-50">
      <a class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" href="#">
        <img id= "icon_calendar" src="../img/icon_calendrier.svg"/>
        <p class="time_date" > 29/12/14</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-50">
      <a class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right" href="#">
        <img class= "icon_size_edit_foot" src="../img/icon_horloge.svg"/>
      <p class="time_date">19h00</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-25">
        <img id="icon_localisation" src="../img/icon_localisation.svg"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-50 venue">
        <p>Le five Bobiny</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-25">
        <img class= "icon_bonhomme" src="../img/icon_bonhomme.svg"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-50 venue">
       <p>Nombre de joueurs <br> (organisateur inclus)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-25 venue">
        <p id="number_players">10</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-25">
        <img class= "icon_bonhomme" src="../img/icon_partager.svg"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-50 venue">
        <p>Vos amis peuvent <br> inviter leurs amis</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-25 venue">
        <ion-toggle id="invite_frient_toggle" ng-model=""
                ng-change="pushNotificationChange()">
        </ion-toggle>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#">
   <div class="text-center"> <p>Niveau du Foot</p></div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col"><img class= "icon_size_edit_foot" src="../img/niveau_1.svg"/><p>Débutant</p></div>
      <div class="col"><img class= "icon_size_edit_foot" src="../img/niveau_2.svg"/><p>Moyen</p></div>
      <div class="col"><img class= "icon_size_edit_foot" src="../img/niveau_3.svg"/><p>Expert</p></div>
      <div class="col"><img class= "icon_size_edit_foot" src="../img/niveau_tous.svg"/><p>Tous</p></div>
   </div>
  </a>
</div>

<button class="button button-block button-positive">
  Valider
</button>

<button class="button button-block button-assertive">
  <img class= "icon_size_edit_foot" src="../img/icon_carton rouge.svg"/>
  Supprimer ce Foot
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, my collegue installed the taskrunner gulp without telling me... Had to run gulp launch for it to work